# Clicking on tab locator for selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble finding out the correct locator for clicking on the tab after logging into the a page

HTML:

```
<td title="Maintenance" id="c1_tab3" class="tabTab noselect tabSelectedTab" onclick="getcontrol( 'c1').setvalue(3);">Maintenance</td>
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void Case1() {
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Transcode Service")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("c1_tab3")).click();
```

Error:

> `FAILED: Case1
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"c1_tab3"}
>     (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)`

Comment: @KirilS. Please don't add `<blockquotes>` to the error trace logs else the log messages gets wrapped up and debugging the log messages becomes difficult.

Comment: @DebanjanB can you please find a rule that would say not to use blockquotes on SO? I actually like them since they separate errors from other things. Also you can combine code and blockquote like I just did. So unless you provide me with a written rule that recommends against it, I will consider your request as a subjective non-binding opinion

Comment: @KirilS. You have interpreted my comment in the worst possible way. I wish you go through it once again. I am not against usage of `<blockquotes>` on SO. Of coarse they separate and highlight the error but that also breaks the _generic_ error log format which is immensely helpful in debugging the error and the message. Hence was my comment.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='c1_tab3' and contains(.,'Maintenance')]")).click();
```

Comment: id doesn't need any additional identifiers, it's unique on the page

Comment: Then he might need to use parent-child relationship to identify the element.